# Setting up MongoDB on Azure

Tags: mongodb, azure

I'm new to Windows Azure. I'm trying to install a fresh MongoDB on Azure VM (virtual machine). I can log in to the machine. I read this article http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MongoDB+on+Azure+VM+-+Windows+Installer that describes how to set it up, but I'm confused about the command

`.\deploy-mongo.ps1 <node-count> <dns-prefix> <image-name> <password> <location> <pub-settings-file-path> [replica-set-name]`

I'm trying to install single MongoDB on azure in a Azure Windows VM that has 20GB harddisk drive.

What is ns-prefix, image-name? Can you give me an example of what that is?

My VM DNS is http://example23231.cloudapp.net. Is it the VM DNS or what?

The  is that also VM image-name like examplevm1_2012_22.vhd?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do what you want you would use

```
.\deploy-mongo.ps1 1 example23231 MyMongoImage MyPassword "West US" PathToPubSettings file
```

The above command will create a single Azure VM instance which is at example23231.cloudapp.net with RDP enabled. It will also download and install MongoDB as a windows service.

If you have an image with name MyMongoImage which is WinRM enabled it will be used. Else an image with that name is created in your default storage account for subsequent uses.

The default image is the standard Windows 2k8R2 image which is 30GB. Note the mongodb datapath is set to the OS drive by default